# Log de errores en Mysql

Tags: mysqli

Como obtener el log de los errores en la base de satos mysql Versión del servidor: 5.1.73 , en mi servidor en centos. Gracias.

Comment: Google puede ayudar: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+log+centos

Answer (score 0):

Los logs por default se guardan bajo la direccion:

```
/var/log
```

a menos que tengas una configuracion distinta a la por defecto.

Mi recomendacion fuera de la pregunta seria la de cambiar la redaccion de tu pregunta, ya que podria recibir votos en contra y ser eliminada.

Suerte.